# Make flags required for angularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, kendo-ui

When this form is loading, I reset the radio buttons' values to `null` so if user doesn't select the value, I can tell.

How can I make radio buttons a required field?

The HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6" ng-show="showrRiskAccpt">
    <div>
        <label class="control-label" for="riskAcceptance">Risk Acceptance</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" id="riskAcceptanceDec" value="Y" 
            ng-model="processRating.riskAcceptanceFlag" 
            ng-change="showRationalCmmt()" 
            ng-required="showrRiskAccpt = true" 
            data-required-msg="Risk Acceptance is required">Yes
        <input type="radio" id="riskAcceptanceDec" value="N"
            ng-model="processRating.riskAcceptanceFlag"  
            ng-change="showRationalCmmt()"
            ng-required="showrRiskAccpt">No
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Simply use required,it sould work.

Comment: Yes with required its working but not showing any message so user dont know where is the errror. How i can display message under that field.

Comment: use  ng-invalid to read error and to display where you want.Go through angular Form documentation.  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: actually i used ng-show for error message if form is invalid. thanks for the help